# Json object array mysql insert

Tags: php, json

I have the following json object:

```
[Object { name="tag[]", value=""w1","x1","y1","z1""}, Object { name="tag[]", value=""w2","x2","y2","y3""}]
```

In php I'm able to store them in an array variable by using post like this:

```
  $tags[] = $_POST['tags'];
  $postid = 1
```

I want to insert the data like so:

```
    Insert Into tagtable  ( postid, w, x, y, z, ,0) values ( $postid, "w1", "x1", "y1", "z1"), ($postid, "w2", "x2", "y2", "z2")


 My problem is getting the comma separated values from the $tags variable.
```

I'm thinking of using a for loop that iterates through the size of the $tags array. Can anyone direct me on how to construct this loop so that I can get a variable like

```
   $alltags = '( $postid, "w1", "x1", "y1", "z1"), ($postid, "w2", "x2", "y2", "z2")';
```

Comment: Did you try to escape the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

try this code .... its depend upon the size of tags array....

```
  $value="";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tags);$i++)
{
     $value .= "($postid,";
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($tag[$i]);$j++)
    {
       $value .="'$tag[$i][$j]',";
    }
    rtrim($value, ",");
    $value .="),";
}
rtrim($value, ",");
$query = "Insert Into tagtable  ( postid, w, x, y, z, ,0) values".$value;
```

Comment: which error you get ??? please mention in error .. it may be `$tag[$i][$j]` `"` error ..